# MySQL Can't seem to concat null field

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQL will not update a null or empty field, but seems ok if I add something to the field before hand.

```
UPDATE trip set MYZID=concat(MYZID, '1,') WHERE id=93
```

Comment: The question is unclear, at least to me. What happens when you have a `null` there, and what would you expect to happen?

Comment: If the field is empty when I update it does not update, but when I add a value before it updates.

Comment: I want it to update the empty field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function [`concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) as stated in the documentation:

> returns NULL if any argument is NULL

so to make it work use [`coalesce()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
UPDATE trip set MYZID=concat(coalesce(MYZID, ''), '1,') WHERE id=93
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Don't think I would have got that - coalesce

Answer (score 2):

From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

> CONCAT() returns NULL if any argument is NULL.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [ifnull](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/control-flow-functions/if-null-function.php) function and set it to empty string in case of null

```
UPDATE trip set MYZID=concat(ifnull(MYZID, ''), '1,') WHERE id=93
```